ScrollSpy active class not working in Bootstrap 5.3.3
I'm creating an app with React, and it has a sidebar where I want to use Bootstrap 5.3.3 ScrollSpy to highlight the items as I scroll down. I followed the documentation (it's actually not the first time I use it) and I think my code is ok, but I can't get the items in the sidebar highlighted as I scroll, because the "active" class is never applied to any of them.
Funny thing, though, is that besides it, I also straight copied a code snippet from the documentation in a test component, and it works. But my sidebar doesn't.
This is my body element, which is supossed to be the scrollable / "spied" element:
<body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#sidebar" data-bs-offset="0" data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" class="scrollspy-example" tabindex="0"> 

This is my sidebar component, where the a anchors should be highlighted as I scroll down the body:
<div id="sidebar" className="grammar-class-list list-group">
     {meanings.map((meaning, index) => (
         <a href={`#grammar-class-${index + 1}`} className="grammar-class list-group-item list-group-item-action">{meaning.partOfSpeech}</a> 
     ))}
</div>

When it compiles, the DOM looks ok to me. The links in the sidebar are clickable and lead to their anchors in the body. But they don't get highlighted, because the active class is never applied.
As I mentioned, I also used this other code from the BS docs as a dummy test, and it works, by "spying" the content where the anchors are, and highlighting them as I scroll.
 <div class="col-4">
   <div id="list-example" className="list-group">
    <a className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-1">Item 1</a>
    <a className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-2">Item 2</a>
    <a className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-3">Item 3</a>
    <a className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" href="#list-item-4">Item 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-8">
  <div>
   <h4 id="list-item-1">Item 1</h4>
   <p>Some content</p>
   <h4 id="list-item-2">Item 2</h4>
   <p>Some more content</p>
   <h4 id="list-item-3">Item 3</h4>
   <p>Some more content</p>
   <h4 id="list-item-4">Item 4</h4>
   <p>Some more content</p>
 </div>
</div>

As you can see, I'm using Scrollspy via data atributtes. I've done it before and it worked, but I don't what's wrong with my sidebar.
I'm using Bootstrap via npm and including it in the body like this:
<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

It's working, because as mentioned the dummy example from the docs works in the same app.
You can see a live example by searching for any word
Anybody has any idea what am I doing wrong? Please feel free to ask for more details if you need them.
Thanks in advance.

After your app finishes parsing and displaying the data from dictionaryapi, you need to run the refresh method. Adding new or different nav elements and their target elements doesn’t trigger scrollspy to update IntersectionObserver. You have to do that in your code using refresh. There is an example of refresh on the Bootstrap Scrollspy page.

Thanks for your answer. However, I'm not sure how to use that refresh method. Actually, I'm not even sure I need it, since there's no non-visible element in the wrapper I'm spying. They get rendered and are visible at the same time (not toggle to show / hide anything, e.g.). They are only non-visible considering you need to scroll to see them, but that's the whole idea of the scrollspy, right? Do I need to refresh anything in this case? Thanks!

For scrollspy to work, you need to run refresh whenever you add or remove elements to the DOM. It’s not that your elements are visible or not, they don’t exist when Bootstrap first loads. If you paste and run the sample code into your browser’s console, you can see the menu items being set to active (you’ll need to set the right values for rootMargin and threshold so scrollspy works for your application). Then you need to incorporate the refresh function in your code that loads the definition.
